# rmarkdown HTML document not showing latex symbols

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have this rmarkdown document which you can run:

It produces an html document on the screen and the

```
 $$  \frac{\mbox{dsfa sdaf lj dsfl}}{dsf}  $$
```

appears correctly but when click close the html document that popped up and open the .html document in the folder it was saved to the above code it not translated to math symbology. Inistead it remains:  $$  \frac{\mbox{dsfa sdaf lj dsfl}}{dsf}  $$

How can I get  $$  \frac{\mbox{dsfa sdaf lj dsfl}}{dsf}  $$ to be translated in the saved html document?

Thank you

Here is the code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{color}
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
fig.lp: ('';character)
fig.pos: "H"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE)

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.


$$  \frac{\mbox{dsfa sdaf lj dsfl}}{dsf}  $$
````

Comment: do you have an internet connection?

Comment: yes I have internet connection

Comment: Cant reproduce the error. Works fine for me. Update all relevant packages.

Comment: Which browser are you opening the file in? We had several computers inexplicably stop rendering with MathJax in IE during the past week. Some still work fine. Works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I am rendering in chrome.

Comment: I am using straight Latex in the code do I need to include something so it recognizes \frac and \mbox ?